# 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found in my private pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, opencv, cocoapods, objective-c++

I'm making a private pod which include opencv and some other algorithm cpp files.But now I get a problem, it is said 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found.
My podspec file is like:

```
    #
    # Be sure to run `pod lib lint podOpenCV.podspec' to ensure this is a
    # valid spec before submitting.
    #
    # Any lines starting with a # are optional, but their use is encouraged
    # To learn more about a Podspec see                 http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html
    #

    Pod::Spec.new do |s|
      s.name             = 'podOpenCV'
      s.version          = '0.1.0'
      s.summary          = 'A short description of podOpenCV.'

    # This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
    #   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
    #   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
    #   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
    #   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!

      s.description      = <<-DESC
     TODO: Add long description of the pod here.
                   DESC

      s.homepage         = 'https://github.com/hudundun90@gmail.com/podOpenCV'
      # s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
      s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
      s.author           = { 'hudundun90@gmail.com' => 'hudun1@qq.com' }
      s.source           = { :git => 'https://github.com/hudundun90@gmail.com/podOpenCV.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
      # s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/<TWITTER_USERNAME>'

      s.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
      s.ios.vendored_libraries = 'podOpenCV/libs/*.a'
      s.ios.vendored_frameworks = 'podOpenCV/libs/opencv2.framework'

    s.source_files = 'podOpenCV/Classes/**/*{.h,.m,.cpp,.mm}'

      # s.resource_bundles = {
      #   'podOpenCV' => ['podOpenCV/Assets/*.png']
      # }

      # s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
      # s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit'
      # s.dependency 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.3'

    s.frameworks = 'Accelerate', 'AssetsLibrary', 'AVFoundation', 'CoreGraphics', 'CoreImage', 'CoreMedia', 'CoreVideo', 'Foundation', 'QuartzCore', 'UIKit', 'OpenGLES'

    s.prefix_header_file = 'podOpenCV/Classes/podOpenCV.pch'

    s.libraries = 'sqlite3', 'z', 'c++', 'stdc++'

    s.xcconfig = {
    'CLANG_CXX_LANGUAGE_STANDARD' => 'c++11',
    'CLANG_CXX_LIBRARY' => 'libc++'
    }

    end
```

Here is my source map.

[image]

[image]

Any help would be great.

Comment: create a podfile and add `pod 'OpenCV'` , then install pod

Comment: what is your framework search path?

Comment: I haved using pod 'OpenCV' before.Now I want to make my private pod with  opencv.

Comment: did you got the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Please add opencv directory to "Header Search Paths"

Comment: I have add this code in podspec   s.xcconfig = {'FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS' => '$(inherited) $(PODS_ROOT)/OpenCV', 'OTHER_LDFLAGS' => '-all_load'}  , but it's not work.

Answer (score -1):

You can go to https://cocoapods.org/ and search for "uses:opencv". That will show you other libraries that depend on OpenCV. From the results, you can check the "See Podspec" link of each library (at the bottom right) and see how they do it. For example [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/0/4/5/CaptchaFace/1.0.4/CaptchaFace.podspec.json) is CaptchaFace's podspec.

I hope that helps a bit!

Comment: I followed these podspec files.When I import opencv to any file in my pod,It still get the same error.Thanks all the way.