# 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, opencv, react-native, npm

I'm using the npm package [react-native-perspective-image-cropper](https://github.com/Michaelvilleneuve/react-native-perspective-image-cropper) and it requires me to install opencv2. In the package's file, it imports opencv2, with the following:

```
#import <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
```

And no matter what I do I keep getting the following error:

> 'opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found

I've read almost every article and question online and I just can't figure it out. I followed the installation steps provided in the article:

- I downloaded opencv2.framework from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/opencvlibrary/files/opencv-ios/2.4.13/) and moved the file opencv2.framework into my `ios` folder.
- Then in XCode, I right clicked on my project, choose add files and selected opencv2.framework

This is when I first got the error. I tried the following fixes to no avail:

- I tried to reinstall and relink the npm package that I was trying to use (I'm not using cocoa pods).
- I tried changing the import to be `#import "opencv2/opencv.hpp"` (replacing the brackets with parenthesis.
- I tried adding opencv2.framework to `Link Binary with Library` under `Build Phases`
- I tried adding opencv2.framework to `Copy Bundle Resources` under `Build Phases`
- I changed `Always Search User Paths (Deprecated)` to `yes`
- I added a `Framework Search Path` of:

  - `$(inherited)`
  - `$(PROJECT_DIR)`
  - `$(PROJECT_DIR)/opencv2.framework`
  - `$(PROJECT_DIR)/./opencv2.framework`
  - `$(PROJECT_DIR)opencv2.framework`
  - `/usr/lib**`
- I added a `Header Search Path` of:

  - `$(inherited)`
  - `$(PROJECT_DIR)`
  - `$(PROJECT_DIR)/opencv2.framework`
  - `$(PROJECT_DIR)/./opencv2.framework`
  - `$(PROJECT_DIR)opencv2.framework`
  - `/usr/lib**`
- I tried moving `opencv2.framework` under the `Framework` folder
- I tried moving `opencv2.framework` directly under the package

I cleaned the product and rebuilt after each attempt and each attempt was attempted at least once (which you can imagine was a ton of fun).

Here are some of the sources I tried to use:

- ['opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13953570/opencv2-opencv-hpp-file-not-found)
- [hpp file in imported framework is not found by XCode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48099572/hpp-file-in-imported-framework-is-not-found-by-xcode)
- [Xcode can't find source files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39605254/xcode-cant-find-source-files)
- ['opencv2/opencv.hpp' file not found in my private pod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42969981/opencv2-opencv-hpp-file-not-found-in-my-private-pod)
- [opencv2/opencv.hpp file not found in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34429936/opencv2-opencv-hpp-file-not-found-in-xcode) (note this is different than #1)
- https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/5989
- https://github.com/kylemcdonald/ofxCv/issues/167
- https://forums.xilinx.com/t5/Vivado-High-Level-Synthesis-HLS/Cannot-find-quot-opencv2-opencv-hpp-quot/td-p/478368
- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/caffe-users/Poteul9Rz20
- http://answers.opencv.org/question/34066/framework-not-found-opencv/
- https://github.com/iMicknl/cordova-plugin-openalpr/issues/12

I genuinely have no clue where to look at this point. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I can also post any updates if more information would be helpful.

Answer (score 2):

you can maybe try cocopod https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenCV or https://cocoapods.org/pods/OpenCV2 in my case I am not sure why I can't install OpenCV2 with cocopod but it stop giving me error after I use cocopod

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I’ll try it out later. I ended up switching to a different library that didn’t require it.